# How to read or Identify ModelState(Valid/Invalid) Errors in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have entered all values which are required on the form. still form doesn't saved in database due to model state returning false i.e Invalid. 
how to identify the issue; means which field has issue due to which the model state returns false? I couldn't identify the exception at runtime in ModelState.

I tried commenting required fields one by one; but that is time consuming.

Finally got the answer to identify ModelState Exceptions at runtime

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(e => e.Errors);
```

Not getting exception at runtime as well as compile time errors.

> Expected Result: Form should save without fail

Comment: please include the compile time error details

Comment: It's hard to tell what your final question is. You ask, in your title, how to get ModelState validation errors, but then your question shows the answer to that question. Please [edit] your question to provide exactly what you are asking. See [ask] for help.